# How to sort alphabetically without repetitious letters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I am trying to sort an input string alphabetically but without repeat two letters beside each other. (abcabc, not aabbcc)
for example, if the input was "aaccbb" the output will be "abcabc"
right now I wrote this line of code. but it just gives me alphabetically sorting. how do I can prevent the repetition of two letters?

```
s = str(input())
s2 = sorted(s)
s3 = "".join(s2)
print(s3)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the logic you have in mind for sorting the string? It can't just be "the string that would appear alphabetically first in the set of all permutations of the original string that don't have consecutive repeating characters", because then the result would be "abacbc", not "abcabc"

Comment: What would be output if the input is aacb?

Comment: What would the output be if the input is "aaab"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matching 3 or more of the same character in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518154/matching-3-or-more-of-the-same-character-in-python)

Comment: just want to sort a string alphabetically without repeat.
if aacb > abca
if aaab ? abaa

something like this: sort from "a" to "z" without two repetitive letters. then sort from beginig again. until sort all characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

def layered_sort(s):
    if not s: return s
    c = Counter(s)
    keys = sorted(c)
    max_repeats = max(c.values())
    return "".join([k for i in range(max_repeats) for k in keys if c[k] > i])

test_cases = (
    "aaccbb",
    "aacb",
    "aaab",
    "the rain in spain falls mainly on the plain"
)

for s in test_cases:
    print(repr(s), "sorts to", repr(layered_sort(s)))
```

Result:

```
'aaccbb' sorts to 'abcabc'
'aacb' sorts to 'abca'
'aaab' sorts to 'abaa'
'the rain in spain falls mainly on the plain' sorts to ' aefhilmnoprsty aehilnpst ailn ailn ain n  '
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools` `count` with `defaultdict` to create tuples with a cumulative counter on character observations.  These tuples are then sorted naturally with `sorted` and we can pluck off the desired element when we `join`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

def goofy_sort(s):

    d = defaultdict(count)
    l = [(next(d[x]), x) for x in s]
    return "".join([y for _, y in sorted(l)])
```

---

Using @Kevin's test cases

```
test_cases = (
    "aaccbb",
    "aacb",
    "aaab",
    "the rain in spain falls mainly on the plain"
)

print(*map(goofy_sort, test_cases), sep="\n")

abcabc
abca
abaa
 aefhilmnoprsty aehilnpst ailn ailn ain n
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a recursive function to do that. I splits the string after the first set is sorted and keeps doing the same with the remaining string

```
def last_part_sort(in_str):
    in_str = sorted(in_str)
    new_str = []
    exclude_ix = []

    for i in range(1, len(in_str)):
        if in_str[i] == in_str[i-1]:
            new_str.append(in_str[i])
            exclude_ix.append(i)

    lead_string = ''.join([in_str[i] for i in range(len(sorted(in_str))) if i not in exclude_ix])

    trail_string = ''.join([s for s in new_str])

    if trail_string == '':
        return lead_string

    return lead_string + last_part_sort(trail_string)
```

For your example

```
last_part_sort(input_str)
out: 'abcabc'
```

For more duplications

```
input_str = 'aaaabbcc'
out: 'abcabcaa'
input_str = 'aaaabbbcc'
out: 'abcabcaba'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"(.)\1{0,}")
r.findall("aaaaaaaabbbbbbccdeeee") # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

The regexp works as follows:

- `.` matches any character
- `(.)` puts that character into a capture group
- `\1` takes the first capture group
- `{0,}` expects zero or more repetitions of that group

Comment: I don't see how this sorts the string. Your input has 21 characters and your output has 5.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP does **not** want the (sorted) set of chars in the input string.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question.